# Is it possible force stable Android resource ids?

Tags: android

I have an app, where I allow the user to pick from a variety of images.  I then save this resource id as a preference.

I'd like the user to be able to upgrade to a newer version of the app, and retain their preferences.  The issue being, if I add additional images to the app, sometimes resource ids will change for already existing images.  This can mean the resource id the user saved in their preferences now points to the wrong image.

Is there any way to enforce a list of resource ids from prior builds so that the id of an existing resource remains constant even after adding more?

Comment: put them in assets, so you access them by name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set ID's you'll use later in R.id class. Then let Android SDK give them unique values during compile time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="my_edit_text_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="my_button_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="my_time_picker_1" type="id"/>

</resources>
```