# How from aapt2 generate the same ID that was generated by aapt?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aapt, aapt2

For some raison I do not yet understand, aapt and aapt2 do not output the same ID. is their any way to force aapt2 to output the same ID generated by aapt ?

Comment: ids are not meant to be stable values so even two versions of aapt or two consecutive runs of aapt would be free to give you different results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302044/is-it-possible-force-stable-android-resource-ids might work but would require you to predefine all of them. In code, you can access them via the id-by-name methods so you don't have to know their actual value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't even force `aapt` resp `aapt2` to guaranteedly assign the same resource IDs in consecutive runs. The IDs in the `R.java` file are static during the app's runtime but will be dynamically assigned during compile time.

For a short discussion on the reasons you might take a look at this Stackoverflow thread on the [purpose and structure of resource IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74382059/why-aapt2-does-not-generate-the-same-id-than-aapt-and-what-the-purpose-of-ids-l/75975892#75975892).

Further, it's [discouraged](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#fromCodeUses) to even touch the `R.java` file and with that the resource IDs. You also don't need to *know* those ID's for any purpose. Just use the common documented ways to [access the app resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Accessing) and you'll be perfectly fine.

NB: There are some methods to predefine IDs as e.g. described in this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302044/is-it-possible-force-stable-android-resource-ids), employing the [R.id](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id) class. But there shouldn't be many real use cases for tricks like that. Usually you'll make things just unnecessarily complicated.